# Where can I find an example of Steihaug's algorithm being used?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

I want to find an example constrained optimisation problem that has been solved using Steihaug's algorithm. I can find brief discussions on Steihaug's algorithm but never an example problem. Does anyone know where I could find one?

Answer (score 1):

[On the Implementation of an Algorithm for Large-Scale Equality Constrained Optimization](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f60c/96056858acc5a582587d19b065fd72175daa.pdf) (1998) [comparison of Steihaug and dogleg algorithms, as discussed in these [lecture notes](http://www.numerical.rl.ac.uk/people/nimg/course/lectures/raphael/lectures/lec7slides.pdf)]